# Specify image url for canvas

Tags: android

I have the following code:

```
canvas.drawBitmap (mBitmap, 0,  0,null);
```

how to I make `mBitmap` as PATH or an image from the SD card? so when I save the canvas, it will save the image from that URL?

Thanks a lot for any help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a URL, you will need to download the byte stream and save and then use BitmapFactory to decode it into a Bitmap Object.

An example of this can be found [here](http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-download-image-from-server-and.html)

The same applies for a file, but you can use [BitmapFactory.decodeFile(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thanks for your respons @Matthew Shea, how about if it's a path?

Comment: Do you mean on the SD card? Just use BitmapFactory.decodeFile(...). That takes a path on the phone.

Comment: yes, what i actually want to do is to save an image file plus the user's drawing on top of it..

Comment: When you create the Canvas, you should be giving it a bitmap object as a backing. Any changes made to the canvas get placed in that bitmap, so just use a reference to that bitmap object and save it to a file.

I don't have the ability to write the code at the moment, and it would likely be useless without some more of yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it, except you create a custom `CustomCanvas` class for your purpose. By any means, you still need to download & cache image before `draw`.

Comment: Thanks for your respons @xjaphx, how about that custom canvas, do you mean I have to create two canvas, one for the bg image and one for the user's drawing?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a [tutorial that does this](https://web.archive.org/web/20201026071708/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2010/11/drawing-with-canvas-in-android-saving.html)

Gist :

Enable drawing cache :

```
 setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
```

Mapping canvas to bitmap :

```
      canvas = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
      if(mBitmap == null){
        mBitmap =  Bitmap.createBitmap (1, 1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);;
      }
      final Canvas c = new Canvas (mBitmap);
      c.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
      commandManager.executeAll(c);
      canvas.drawBitmap (mBitmap, 0,  0,null);
```

Saving the image :

```
final FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(APP_FILE_PATH + "/myAwesomeDrawing.png"));
      nBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
      out.flush();
      out.close();
```

Comment: thanks for your response @Reno, will this save the image + user's drawing?

Comment: I'm actually following that tutorial, thanks for pointing this out.